# Why cannot I find a string using this method in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    if 'Sudarshan' in f.read():
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

#The logins.txt file content:

```
Username: Sudarshan
```

it always shows me "false"

Comment: Everything after the first line in your code should be indented by four more spaces, as it belongs to the `with` block. Otherwise, the code looks fine. If its result is unexpected, check your txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file open statement, you are reading the file only once. You need to have a for loop to check if the file has the record 'Sudarshan'. Each record read will also end with a \n. So you first need to strip it.

Try this:

```
check = False
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Sudarshan' in line:
            check = True

if check:
    print("File has Sudarshan")
else:
    print("File does not have Sudarshan")
```

Or you can also do something like this

```
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

if 'Sudarshan' in lines:
    print("File has Sudarshan")
else:
    print("File does not have Sudarshan")
```